# Access Vue Data from Event listener ( Laravel )

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a multistep form using Vue to do that i want to create one component for each step lets say:

StepOne.vue StepTwo.vue StepThree.vue

In my app.js i have a event listener and a variable called step.

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return data = {
            step : 1
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.' + this.step)
    },
    created() {
        Event.$on('start', function(par){
            console.log('got it' + this.step);
        })
    }
});
```

When the event is emmited in my StepOne component the **console logs: got it undefined.**

In my blade view i want to do something like this:

```
<div id="app">
    If step == 1 show StepOne
    If step == 2 show StepTwo
    if step == 3 show StepThree
</div>
```

Is this the right approach?

Comment: it should be `return {step : 1}` without `data =`

Answer (score 0):

use `window.events` to listen for an event, and make sure u change the data return like below!

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        Dashboard,
    },
    data: function() {
        return  {
            step : 1
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.' + this.step)
    },
    created() {
        window.events.$on('start', function(par){
            console.log('got it' + this.step);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry i did forget to mention that i have a window.Event = new Vue();

Comment: Anyway, i changed the data function, and used the local window.Event.$on console still logs out 'got it: undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this.step inside a Event is calling the "wrong" data source since a had an window.Event = new Vue(); this was actually calling the data from there ( i believe )

Changing this to app.step worked.

```
window.Event = new Vue();

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            step : 1
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.' + this.step)
    },
    created() {
        Event.$on('start', function(par){
            console.log('got it ' + app.step);
        })
    }
});
```

Thanks everyone for the help!